# Inverting Kronecker product on vectors is in P?

Tags: np-hardness, permutations

Problem: Given a vector V of positive integers, find two vectors v1 and v2 such that the Kronecker product of v1 and v2 is equal to p(V) (where p(V) is a suitable permutation of V).

Example:
Input: V={8,4,18,9,12,24,36,16,48}.
Output: v1={4,9,12}, v2={2,4,1}

Kronecker product of v1 and v2 is {8,16,4,18,36,9,24,48,12}
which is a permutation of V.

I do not know whether this problem is NP-hard or can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: What's p?  Is p given as an input?  Do you mean to say "such that there exists p so that the Kronecker product..."?  Are all vectors required to be over the positive integers?  the rationals?  something else?

Comment: There is always a trivial solution where $v_1=(1)$ and $v_2=v$.  I suspect you mean to ask about non-trivial solutions.  If you factor each number $x$ as $x=p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$ where $p_1,\dots,p_k$ are the set of primes that divide at least one of the numbers of $v$, and then map the number $x$ to the vector $(e_1,\dots,e_k)$, then your problem reduces to a similar one about inverting Minkowski sums: see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/32444/5038.  I don't know whether that is helpful.

Comment: Can you please state your definition of the Kronecker product of two vectors? The definition I know yields an $n\times m$ matrix (if one vector has length $n$ and the other one has length $m$).

Comment: reply to comments: 
- p is a permutation and is not given . the problem is indeed to find the right permutation such that the input vector can be written as the Kronecker product of two other smaller vectors
- vectors are of positive integers and solutions must be of positive integers
- trivial solution with v1={1} is not of interest
- Kronecker product: v1={a,b,c}, v2={d,e},  v1 x v2={ad,ae,bd,be,cd,ce}

Comment: I assume v1 and v2 have to be integer vectors?  Now, what about the case where $|V|=1$?  So $V=\{q\}$ for some integer $q$.  Then it seems you are asking to find a non-trivial factor of $q$.  If this is your intended meaning in this case, then isn't your problem is at least as hard as factoring?